# __makeref as a way to get a reference value in C#?

Tags: c#, clr

I've seen this code which was used showing the reference value :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s1 = "ab";
    string s2 = "a"+"b";
    string s3 = new StringBuilder("a").Append("b").ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(GetMemoryAddress(s1));
    Console.WriteLine(GetMemoryAddress(s2));
    Console.WriteLine(GetMemoryAddress(s3));
}

static IntPtr GetMemoryAddress(object s1)
{
    unsafe
    {
        TypedReference tr = __makeref(s1);
        IntPtr ptr = **(IntPtr**) (&tr);
        return ptr;
    }
}
```

Result (as expected):

[image]

*(I know that string interning kicks in here, but that's not the question).*

**Question:**

Although it seems that it does do the job, 
Does using `__makeref` is this the right way of getting the reference value in c#?

Or are there any situations in which this ^ would fail ....?

Comment: Just curious why do you need this? AFAIK garbage collector can move objects in compaction phase, so address can become invalid in amy moment

Comment: @AleksAndreev Yes GC can do whatever it wants:-). but till he does, I want to know if those references value can be checked. I have a lecture on this. In short - curiosity.

Comment: a: this is a terrible idea; b: if this is *specifically* related to strings, `fixed(char* ptr = theString) {...}` gives you a pointer to the char data; c: I wouldn't touch `__makeref` with a very long pole... d: what are you actually trying to do, and why? if we understand *that*, we can give appropriate guidance

Comment: e: "showing the address of a variable" - be careful with that phrasing - you haven't shown the address of a *variable*; you've shown the address of an *object* accessed from a variable - very different things, and it matters

Comment: @MarcGravell A mistake of mine. I did edit the title and forgot to edit the line in question. updating.

Comment: I don't think the code does what you think it does... `&tr` is the address of the local on the stack, not the unmanaged pointer to which it relates - after that, you're relying on layout inside the `struct`, which... eesh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Although it seems that it does do the job, Does using `__makeref` is this the right way of getting the reference value in c#?

There is no "right way" of doing this in C# - it isn't something you're meant to try and do, but: in terms of *what* it is doing - this is essentially relying on the internal layout of `TypedReference` and a type coercion; it'll *work* (as long as `TypedReference` doesn't change internally - for example the order of the `Type` and `Value` fields changes), but... it is nasty.

There is a more direct approach; in IL, you can convert from a *managed pointer* to an *unmanaged pointer* silently. Which means you can do something nasty like:

```cs
unsafe delegate void* RefToPointer(object obj);
static RefToPointer GetRef { get; } = MakeGetRef();
static RefToPointer MakeGetRef()
{
    var dm = new DynamicMethod("evil", typeof(void*), new[] { typeof(object) });
    var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    return (RefToPointer)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(RefToPointer));
}
```

and now you can just do:

```cs
var ptr = new IntPtr(GetRef(o));
Console.WriteLine(ptr);
```

This is **horrible**, and you should never do it - and of course the GC can move things while you're not looking (or even while you *are* looking), but... it works.

Whether ref-emit is "better" than undocumented and unsupported language features like `__makeref` and type-coercion: is a matter of some debate. Hopefully *purely academic* debate!

Comment: Thanks. For not being an XY problem - All I wanted is to show colleagues, a proof that `""` is exactly the same reference to `String.empty` in a non `Object.referenceEquals((object)s1,(object)s2)` way. ( to actually show the pointer value

Comment: @RoyiNamir hmmm; it may need hints on some frameworks to disable verification - not at PC now, though - but: if your main aim is `""`, frankly, you should probably stick with `fixed (char* c = theString) { Console.WriteLine(new IntPtr(c)); }`